# Powershell XML filter

Tags: xml, powershell, filtering

I am trying to delete files in a folder based on any folder containing an XML file with the tag Modality containing anyType="CT" but quickly an into an issue trying to filter by XML content

I am able to return some content, but as soon as I try any filtering or to try and drill down into the content I get an empty result.

This is as deep as I can query and still return content from the xml file

```
$xmlfile = get-Content .\7.86.7.7053.61.159438.472144765.1719.XML
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement.ElementName
```

as soon as I try to drill deeper down I get no result e.g.

```
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement.Elementname |where {$_.name -eq "Modality"}
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement.Elementname |where {$_.name -eq "anyType"}
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement.Elementname |where {$_.name -eq "CT"}
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement | where {$_.name -eq "00080060"}
```

Here is a copy of the XML I am trying to filter I am assuming it is due to the format of the XML file I am having so much difficulty or just a massive misunderstanding of XML format or how powershell interacts with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPublicXMLElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <PublicXMLElement>
    <ElementName>Acquisition Time</ElementName>
    <Tag>00080032</Tag>
    <VR>TM</VR>
    <ElementData>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">105343</anyType>
    </ElementData>
  </PublicXMLElement>    <ElementName>Accession Number</ElementName>
    <Tag>00080050</Tag>
    <VR>SH</VR>
    <ElementData>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    </ElementData>
  </PublicXMLElement>
  <PublicXMLElement>
    <ElementName>Modality</ElementName>
    <Tag>00080060</Tag>
    <VR>CS</VR>
    <ElementData>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">CT</anyType>
    </ElementData>
  </PublicXMLElement>
  <PublicXMLElement>
    <ElementName>Station Name</ElementName>
    <Tag>00081010</Tag>
    <VR>SH</VR>
    <ElementData>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M_Source</anyType>
    </ElementData>
  </PublicXMLElement>
  <PublicXMLElement>
    <ElementName>Rescale Slope</ElementName>
    <Tag>00281053</Tag>
    <VR>DS</VR>
    <ElementData>
      <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0</anyType>
    </ElementData>
  </PublicXMLElement>
</ArrayOfPublicXMLElement>
```

Comment: The XML is invalid. The first `</PublicXMLElement>` has no matching start tag.

Comment: I would assume then there is nothing I can do about it? I am unable to change the XML.

Comment: Who or what prevents you to get a valid XML? If you can't edit it, all you have is [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: I would like to apologise, I had trimmed the document as the full XML file has around 1635. I trimmed 1 line too many !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you have is invalid XML, and if I understand correctly that you wish to remove all of these files where:

- there is a tag `<ElementName>Modality</ElementName>`
- that has an tag `<ElementData>`,
- which in turn has a tag `<anyType>` containing value `CT`

then you will have to resort to using regex.

```
$regex = '(?s)<ElementName>Modality</ElementName>.*<ElementData>\s*<anyType[^>]*>CT</anyType>'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    if ($content -match $regex) {
        $_ | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf  # see below
    }
}
```

<sup>Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied the code would remove the correct files to actually delete those.</sup>

**Regex details**

```
(?s)                                    Dot matches line breaks
<ElementName>Modality</ElementName>     Match the character string “<ElementName>Modality</ElementName>” literally
.                                       Match any single character
   *                                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
<ElementData>                           Match the character string “<ElementData>” literally
\s                                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
   *                                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
<anyType                                Match the character string “<anyType” literally
[^>]                                    Match any character that is NOT a “>”
   *                                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>CT</anyType>                           Match the character string “>CT</anyType>” literally
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this working the way you like it?

```
$xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement | Where-Object { ($_.ElementName -like "Modality") -and ($_.ElementData.anyType.InnerText -like "CT")}
```

This is an easy method to get the number of matches:

```
(@($xmlfile.ArrayOfPublicXMLElement.PublicXMLElement | Where-Object { ($_.ElementName -like "Modality") -and ($_.ElementData.anyType.InnerText -like "CT")})).Count
```

Comment: Hi Apologies for not replying sooner, this is how I imagined it to work in powershell, but for some reason I get an empty result every time I try to go about this method of querying the XML file. 
The response above from Theo is working for me, but I would like to thank you for your time taken in answering my question, and my apologies that I cannot get it to work.
The count matches 0 )

Comment: And perseverance counts !! 
turns out that I was rather daft in missing the [xml] 
as soon as I added that it was able to return the results I wanted !!!! 

THANK YOU AS WELL

I cannot have 2 answers although both resolve my issue !!